# Linux Find command source code

Tags: linux, terminal, find

When I type find into my terminal, this is the output I get:

```
My-MacBook-Air:desktop User$ find
usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
       find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]
```

How does my computer know where the source code for this command is and how can I access it myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok well ... first this is probably not Linux but MacOS? But no matter what, your computer doesn't use any source code but a compiled executable, that is located somewhere in your search path -- a list of directories that are searched when you enter a command, typically something like `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`

You can display your search path with `echo $PATH` and find the full location of `find` with `which find`.

No idea what version of `find` comes with MacOS ... if you're *really* interested in source code, you could download the version typically installed on linux systems here: http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/findutils/

Comment: So the way my computer calls the find command is through an executable binary script?

Comment: It's not a script ("binary script" somehow contradicts itself). It is native executable code in an executable file. This is actually true for most programs you run nowadays. Notable exceptions are Java or .NET programs (which run in a virtual machine, but are still binary) and, well, scripts (which are readable source in text form, interpreted at run time).